# Check in an array ids are equals to dispatch the id value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, foreach

I create an array of ids value mapping an existing array

```
const ids = array.map(item => ({ id: item.homologationId }));
```

This is the result

```
ids =[{ "id": "15079"},{"id": "15079"},{"id": "15079"},{"id": "15079"},]
```

From here i want to check if for each item of the ids array the id values are the same ( like in this example ) i want to dispatch in the store the id value `(dispatch(setIdValue(value));`

How can i do this check?

Comment: If you only need to dispatch exactly when 'ALL' values are the same, then may be this works: `const uniqIds = new Set(array.map(item => item.homologationId)); if (uniqIds.size === 1) dispatch(setIdValue(uniqIds.values().next().value));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) Javascript Array method.

Something like this will do the trick.

```
const ids = array.map(item => ({ id: item.homologationId }));
const [head] = ids
if (head && ids.every(item => item.id == head.id)) {
    dispatch(setIdValue(head.id))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use every function to check the equality of the ids, this function returns true if the all the elements in an iterable fulfills a condition.

```js
const ids =[{ "id": "15079"},{"id": "15079"},{"id": "15079"},{"id": "15079"}]

const element = ids.at(0);
if(ids.every(x => x.id === element.id)) {
  console.log("All the elements are equals")
} else {
  console.log("Not all the elements are equals")
}
```